# Store result into cache in Play 2.2

Tags: caching, playframework-2.0, ehcache

In Play framework 2.2 is very simple to create an result of the current request. We type just:

```
Ok(views.html.default.render())
```

And then to make it work is enough to wrap it by Action, so the final code looks like:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.default.render())
}
```

That is fine. But now, I want to store the response in cache to make it more scalable. I use EHCache. The issue is, that when I store it into cache, it throws

```
NotSerializableException: play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1
```

I tried to cache at least the result it self, but it throws

```
ERROR net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory Disk Write of result-key failed: 
java.io.NotSerializableException: play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator$$anon$18
```

I know, that the values are stored in the cache, but only in a memory, which might be very insufficient considering really high load and many distinct responses.

### Question:

So my question is whether there is any way how to fully cache Play actions/results, including proper serialization?

### Edit:

How I try to use the cache: I do not use `Cached {}` because it doesn't behave exactly how I need, so I try to designed it in my own way. So just for the testing purposes I use it more verbosely by now:

```
Cache.set("myaction", Action {
  Ok(views.html.default.render())
})
```

or

```
Cache.set("myresponse", Ok(views.html.default.render()))
```

But both of these produces exceptions mentioned above.

About the cache: The Play cache API is not sufficient to me, so I extended it by another couple methods together with new plugin implementation. At first I tried to just copy default plugin and implement those extensions but there were some issues, so I fixed them is recommended [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/PBIfeiwl5rU/discussion). It is the plugin fix. Since then it seems that it actually uses the EHCache (guessing from those exceptions).

Comment: How are you storing the result to Cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not trying to store the results in the cache but the action, which then contains a closure that cannot be serialized, I guess this is not what you want to do anyways, I guess this is because you are using EHCache directly?

If you use the Play cache API it should help you do the right thing. You can find the docs for it here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCache

The response may still not be serializable though, if you really want a cache that serializes to disk you should be able to cache the HTML generated by the template as it is basically a string, and then re-use that but create a new response for every request.

(My gut feeling is that you would probably get better performance from rendering the template every time than the cache reading it from disk unless you have some really crazy complex templates)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to store both the results and the actions - I said it in question and about the action you are probably right. I am not sure what do you mean by using cache directly, but I have improved default implementation a bit. Please check out my question edit. You said that caching actions is not good idea. What about caching results themself? Just like I showed in the edit. Anyway I wonder how the Play cache works because the caching responses is there supported ... is it just some memcache without serialization to FS or so?

Comment: It never serializes, just keeps objects in memory. You can find the default play cache config in the play.jar/ehcache.xml and in the play sources that accompanies the play distribution where you can also take a closer look at the cache implementation to see how it works.

Comment: So if I want to cache also action for quick responses, you recommend me to use two caches? One with serialization for common data and another one without it for results?

Comment: I think you should look at the implementation of the class Cached to understand how it works and then implement your customizations based on that understanding. Also, make sure to benchmark/profile, maybe just caching the data your reply needs is what you need and the action logic is insignificant!

Comment: it is a enlightening question and answer even for 2.4.x. I had the (almost) same problem using redis as cache module. Now I really had a problem with play's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is suitable for 2.2, however according to this [issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5274) I reported

if you're calling `set` method directly from an implementation of CacheApi and the implementation expects a serializable object, use this [wrapper](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/SerializableResult.scala) which is also used by the `@cached` helper.